# Receive Excel Msg pop up when we're on other tools

Tags: excel, msgbox

I was able to make a live countdown in Excel and was able to get a message pop-up when the countdown hits 0.

However, when I'm on other browsers such as Google etc and when the countdown hits 0, I won't be notified until I open up my Excel. Is there a way to get notified by Excel while I'm using other browsers?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("E2:E7")
    If Format$(c.Value, "HH:MM:SS") = "00:15:00" Then
        MsgBox "Block " & c.Offset(0, -3).Value & " ends in 15 mins"
    End If
```

This is the code that I have.

Comment: This probably is done by VBA. If so it is vital to know what methods you use, so please share your code.

Comment: Hi @Luuklag, I have added the code.

Comment: From the mrexcel forums I found: add this line right infront of your MsgBox line `AppActivate Application.Caption`. credit to user dk

Comment: @Luuklag Sorry but it doesn't seems to work

Comment: Another user mentioned to use DoEvents inbetween like such: `AppActivate Application.Caption
    DoEvents` from https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/66245-ensure-msgbox-pops-up-top.html